# Aws ec2 cloudshell 169.254.169.254/latest/ returns resource not found. How can i get meta data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i run ec2 instance in aws
the i run cloudshell, where i want to get instance meta data, so i want to run

curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

to get meta data, following
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

but i am getting
Resource not found: /latest/meta-data/

how can i access meta data ?

thanks

Comment: The instance metadata server is rather limited on the host that the Cloudshell docker environment runs on.  You won't be able to get most information for the host machine since it's a shared machine.  You should be able to run that command on a normal EC2 instance.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to access the metadata?

Comment: i was about to get information in which AZ current instance is running

Comment: Cloud Shell doesn't run from the instance your created, I believe this is an XY problem

Comment: If you want to get information about an EC2 instance that you launched, use `aws ec2 describe-instances`, giving it the instance ID. You should be able to run that from CloudShell if you have the correct permissions. If you want to do something different, then you'll need to rewrite your question to be more explicit.